# Export the contents of a GraphWin to an image file

Tags: image, python-3.x, export, zelle-graphics

Is there any chance I can save 'image' created in GraphWin to file? It does not matter what type, I just need to store it for later comparsion.

```
win = GraphWin("Test image", 500, 500)
c = Circle(Point(Items[i].x, Items[i].y), Items[i].z)
c.setFill(color)
c.draw(win)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, since GraphWin is a subclass of Tkinter Canvas, you can do:

```
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin("Test image", 500, 500)
c = Circle(Point(100, 100), 50)
c.setFill("green")
c.draw(win)

win.postscript(file = "graphic.eps")
```